# How can I get given month start date and end date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to get given month start date and end date.

```
   var currentDate = new Date();
   var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
```

Comment: Check [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) library and its `startOf` and `endOf` methods. Your question is not connected to AngularJS as it does not provide its own date manipulation methods (i.e. it is [pure JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) question).

Comment: Note that you can get momentjs wrapped as a service for angular, ie: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-momentjs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
function MyCtrl($scope){
   var date = new Date(), year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth();
   var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
   var lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
   $scope.firstDay = firstDay ;
   $scope.lastDay = lastDay ;
   $scope.date = date ;    
}
```

And:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul>
    <li>{{date | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</li> 
    <li>{{firstDay | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</li> 
    <li>{{lastDay | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you yiabiten. This is what I asked. I have used this code. Thank you so much.